# Sardinia COVID-19 registration for tourists

Tags: regulations, covid-19, registration, sardinia

I've been noticed by a friend that Sardinia currently requires advanced registration before travelling due COVID-19. The registration page is in Italy, no English, so I'll ask the embassy. But maybe somebody here knows more.

https://sus.regione.sardegna.it/sus

Answer (score 2):

OK, according to [Czech embassy in Italy](https://www.mzv.cz/rome/cz/viza_a_konzularni_informace/konzularni_informace_pro_italii/rady_pro_cesty_na_sardinii_sicilii_do.html) [in Czech], it's needed *either* to be registered on http://www.regione.sardegna.it/ *or* since 12th June it's possible to fill this form on the airplane and hand it in to the officers in Sardinia.

The online registration form appears to be: https://sus.regione.sardegna.it/sus/covid19/regimbarco/init
(found on http://www.regione.sardegna.it/j/v/2834?s=1&v=9&c=94253&na=1&n=8&c1=289&nodesc=1&ph=1&c1=3).

It also requires to add at least 1 location (address) where traveller is planning to stay (ID appointed there is required).

After registration, the autority will send you an email with a confirmation ID and an additional link to another form (health check and possible covid-19 infections) that is mandatory to file-in 48h before the departure date.

http://www.regione.sardegna.it/xml/getpage.php?cat=65 states that
for more information about this process, it's best to send an email at: 
`urp.emergenza@regione.sardegna.it`

**UPDATE:** after filling a form I got confirmation with assigned *ID* and *GUID* and link to my form where I'm required to fill my health status declaration 48 hours before the boarding date.