# Sleeping in Sardinia

Tags: legal, covid-19, sleeping, campers, sardinia

Is it allowed to sleep outside (with a tent or just in a sleeping bag; not in the car) in Sardinia?

Especially due covid rules, which require [registration](https://sus.regione.sardegna.it/sus/covid19/regimbarco/init) before travelling where it requires address (see [Sardinia COVID-19 registration for tourists](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/157622/sardinia-covid-19-registration-for-tourists)).